# SWIFT: how to run a function even when user kills the app

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, xcode7, background-process

I am using swift 2 and Xcode7 for iOS9.  I want to know if I can maintain a function (that checks for something to delete) running "forever" even if the user kills the app?

I am deleting contacts from the contact list according to some rules and time. It is running ok, but just with the app opened or in second plan. I want to make this app capable to delete those contacts even when the user kills it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use background thread when user opens the app. But if the app will be terminated, there is no option to run functions.
Look for the app lifecycle here and redesign your architecture: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: but how I can still receive messages on whatsapp for example, even if I kill it?

Comment: it's not killed. It is running as a background process, created automatically when the system starts. You are closing fronted app, not a background process. If you will kill this process, you will not get messages.

Comment: so if I double click Home button and remove an app from that "list", I am not killing the app, just the fronted app?

Comment: You are closing the app, but you can have background process, that it will be still alive. When you install the app you somehow agree to install also background process (it's different than the fronted app). I am not sure how What'sApp architecture looks like in detail, but first check above-mentioned docs.

Comment: "but how I can still receive messages on whatsapp for example, even if I kill it?". PUSH NOTIFICATION is your answer.

Comment: Exactly. Read about APNS push notification system on Apple dev sites.

Answer (score 1):

If the user kills the app it is no longer running, therefore your code is no longer running. There is no such state that your code/app can be in where this is possible.

By "kill", I don't mean "background". Backgrounding an app is different. Check Apple's docs on the different app states (see m.albin's answer) as well as various [strategies for handling those app states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html).

Comment: but how I can still receive messages on whatsapp for example, even if I kill it?

Comment: I think it would be good if you read the app life cycle document as well as the strategies document. It sounds like you don't fully understand what the Background state means and how it is different from when your app gets "killed".

Answer (score 1):

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    print("Application Will Terminate")
}
```